# How make NuGet package run commands/logic on install even on linux/mac/windows?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

It appears that the old way of running commands (`init.ps1`) on install is deprecated? https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4318

And that is powershell, which won't work on linux. Our .Net projects can be built by devs on Linux, Mac and Windows.

Is there a mechanism that we can hook into to run some commands or code when our NuGet package is installed via the command line or Visual Studio's NuGet package manager?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do / execute, you could get recommendations on what other features you could use to accomplish the task?

Comment: @MartinUllrich We need to upgrade a few hundred services to new code patterns as well as to .net core. So convert the app.config to appSettings.json along with other changes too. So we want to run a bunch of scripts or code that converts everything by just pulling it into the old projects.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was [deprecated](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4318) when the new PackageReference format came.

I *think* the proper way to do what you're asking for now is through a [.NET Core Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools). A .NET Core Tool is essentially a NuGet containing an executable application. You build a .NET Core Tool with `dotnet publish`, and consume it with:

1. `dotnet tool install -g dotnetsay`
2. `dotnetsay`

.NET Core Tool came in .NET Core 2.1, so should be more mature now in 3.1. They seem powerful to me, altough I haven't really built anything with them yet.